# Alchemy Websockets: Can't host server on Azure

Tags: c#, android, azure, websocket, azure-web-roles

I'm currently using [Alchemy Websockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) as my WebSocket solution, however this is proving to be a pain as I've spent quite a number of hours trying to figure out why I can't get it up and going on my WebRole (both on Compute Emulator and cloudapp.net itself). It runs **okay** locally.

I'm aware of [this question that was asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849854/deploying-web-socket-server-on-windows-azure), and I've followed everything in the code and done everything suggested, so I can't get why I still can't connect to my WebSocket server. I've tried connecting using [WebSocket.org's Echo Test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) as well as an Android client (leveraging on [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/android/)). I'm quite sure it's not a client-side issue anymore considering that both ways don't work, but more of a server-side issue (what is stopping me from opening the WebSocket server on Azure?!).

In summary, what I've done so far:

1. Included TCP InputEndpoint 8080 in my Azure
2. Start the WebSocket server in either `Global.asax` or `RoleEntryPoint` with port 8080
3. Tried connecting using both Echo Test & Autobahn for Android

If it helps, I've previously tried [SuperWebSocket Server](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/). I understand that the creator Kerry Jiang has uploaded some Azure samples, but the Command Assembly baffles me and I don't want that kind of extra logic in my application (I just want something that I can plug and play), so I decided to ditch that altogether.

Both Alchemy Websockets and SuperWebSocket Server work perfectly fine locally, but when it's on Azure (either emulator on uploaded on cloudapp.net) I can't seem to connect at all. Any guidance please...?

Comment: I don't know next to nothing about Azure, but here is a problem you might run into: intermediaries (network devices like firewalls, load-balancer and such) that aren't WebSocket compatible or filter it actively. Here is what I would try: use secure WebSocket (WSS). Terminating the TLS on your server. Run that with a valid certificate over standard 443. This will rule out interference by intermediaries.

Comment: Thanks bro! After configuring the VM's firewall to accept incoming port requests ([here's the link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureAddFirewallRules-352de4ed)) it works! You could prolly write up a quick answer and I'll give thanks for it. One issue though, my CPU usage on my VM is always at 100%, what is wrong with my WebSocket implementation here??

Comment: Sorry, I don't use .Net, SuperWebSocket nor Azure. I'd contact the authors of the server framework. In general, I can assure you: you can use WS with capable servers that won't produce any (significant) CPU load with millions of WS (when those are idle of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using WebSocket with cloud-hosted VMs, a number of things can go wrong:

1. The cloud service might have firewalls in place that block any (non-standard) ports by default. On Amazon EC2, you can configure open (unblocked) inbound ports via AWS management console and the respective configuration of the "security group" that applies to the EC2 instance your WS server is running on.
2. Even if you use a standard Web port (like 80) and this port is open in the firewall, there might be a proxy, load-balancer or other so-called intemediary in place that is not WebSocket aware.
3. When running over non-local networks, there are all kinds of intermediaries that might interfere. For example, mobile networkwork providers have intermediaries that are too stupid for WebSocket (which uses the HTTP *standard* Upgrade mechanism .. it is standard .. but there is a lot of broken stuff out there).
4. To work around for 2. and 3. (and also in general), you probably want to run WebSocket over TLS (secure WebSocket .. WSS) in production. Running over TLS, and terminating the TLS connection *at your server*, no intermediary can interfere (there are exceptions even here .. so called MITM HTTPS proxies that unwrap the TLS .. but that only on some corporate networks and relies on the proxy being able to dynamically installing certificates in the user's browser).
5. To make a robust WSS connection, you MUST make sure the server certificate used is accepted by browsers without any problems. If it is self-signed e.g., a browser would normally not accept, but ask the user if he nevertheless wants to accept. With WS, the browser *will not* render such dialogs, because WS is a so called "subresource". Hence: make sure your cert is 100% ok.
6. With 5. being done, WebSocket (WSS then), *will* work (almost) all the time. Mobile, enterprise, public internet.